# Register User via SMS in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, sms, twilio

I am setting up an App Engine application, and I want to register all my users based on their phone number (like Whatsapp).

The server will need to send an SMS to the user to authenticate. Then the user can log in with a combination of their phone number + password.

Does Google Apps support this type of authentication model, or do I have to use a Google Account?

I saw Twilio support, but that seems more for setting up an app that sends a bunch of SMSes/VoIP server side.  I just need to receive one SMS per user to confirm their phone number.

Note: this will be a iOS/Android app, with possible web support in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The App Engine does not force you to use any authentication mechanism. You can choose Google Account option when creating your app, and you may find it useful for admin logins, for example, but you don't have to use it for all users of your app.

The App Engine does not offer a built-in support for SMS authentication, but there is nothing that prevents you from using it. Twilio API offers all the tools that you need.

Note that SMS authentication model has major limitations. For example, people tend to change phones and sometimes their phone numbers, and they typically lose access to the previous phone/number immediately upon switching, which makes it difficult to transfer their accounts. This is one of the reasons why more apps choose a two-step verification (username/password with SMS confirmation) as opposed to a single-step SMS-only approach.

Comment: True. I was thinking about registering a phone number and then adding email/password to it as a second step. Thanks!